# Cosa significa "non era d'abito spogliante" in questa frase?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Il barone rampante*, di Italo Calvino, ho letto:

> Poi venne il tempo della violenza distruggitrice: ogni albero, cominciava dalla vetta e, via una foglia via l'altra, rapidissimo lo riduceva bruco come d'inverno, anche se **non era d'abito spogliante**.

Questa frase fa riferimento a Cosimo, il barone rampante, protagonista del libro.

La mia domanda è sul senso dell'espressione "non era d'abito spogliante".  Significa che Cosimo non aveva l'abitudine di spogliare gli alberi delle sue foglie? Vuol dire che non si trattava di un albero di foglia caduca? Oppure il significato è un altro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L'espressione è riferita all'albero che non era d'abito spogliante cioè non era un albero a foglie caduche ma era un sempreverde.

Ciò che l'inverno faceva agli alberi a foglie caduche lui in preda alla rabbia lo faceva a quelli sempreverdi strappando le foglie, ed andava anche oltre scorticandoli e privandoli della corteccia.